# Sorting on mongo DB giving unexpected result

Tags: mongodb

I am tring to add document in a collection .After adding data to collection.Then applying sorting .

[image]

I attached snapshot  that shows sorting not happening properly.

Comment: I think it is because value of frequency field in string not integer. Try inserting integer values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be attributed to the fact that you are not actually setting the `frequency` value to a number, but to a string instead. Try settings the frequency as a number (i.e. without the enclosing quotes) and it will work as you'd expect. For example:

`db.commerce.insert({frequency: 1})`